# ng-table - how do I get the current page number

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using ng-table to load and display a big array with pagination. When the user gets to the penultimate page, I want to automatically concatenate another set of lines to the table.

**How do I get the current page number from ng-table, please?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

html: `tableParams.page`

js:   `self.tableParams.page()`

More info: [ngTable-pagination](http://ng-table.com/#/pagination/demo-api)